# stateParams vs $stateParams with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am confused. For a long time now I have been using stateParams as a means of find out the stateParams inside a templateUrl.

Now I tried to do the same in a resolve and it does not work. In fact nothing happens when I use stateParams.

However by chance I found that I can use $stateParams in the resolve and it works.

Can someone tell me what is the difference and why do I need to use stateParams in the templateUrl and $stateParams in the resolve?

```
   var auth = {
        name: 'auth',
        url: '/Auth/:content',
        templateUrl: function (stateParams) {
            var page = 'app/auth/partials/' + stateParams.content + '.html';
            return page;
        },
        controller: function ($scope, authService) {
            $scope.aus = authService;
        },
        resolve:
        {
            init: function ($stateParams) {
                var x = 99;
                return true;
            }
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4JWbKm1jPvSlvuBmiSJU?p=preview), showing that `$statePrams` are accessible in the resolve

```
// States
$stateProvider
  .state('auth', {
      url: "/auth/:content",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl',
      resolve : {
        init : ['$stateParams' , function($stateParams){
          return { resolved: true, content: $stateParams.content };
        }]
      }
  })
```

Controller

```
.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', 'init', function ($scope, init) { 
  $scope.init = init;
}])
```

and this could be the calls

```
<a href="#/auth/8">auth/8</a>
<a href="#/auth/xyz">auth/xyz</a>
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4JWbKm1jPvSlvuBmiSJU?p=preview)

Comment: You are correct. $stateParameters is there in the resolve and it works okay.  But I am wondering about why it's okay to use stateParameters in the template but not in the resolve. Should I be using $stateParameters in the template.  Just really wondering what the difference between the two is and why one works in one place and not the other.

Comment: Check my updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4JWbKm1jPvSlvuBmiSJU?p=preview - different template for different content param (8 is NUMBER)